# Microsoft Graph User last modified field

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to filter the Users endpoint by a date modified field.

I tried `lastModifiedDateTime ge 2020-01-01T00:00:00Z` however it throws an error `"Property 'lastModifiedDateTime' does not exist as a declared property or extension property."`

There are no [datetime fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) that resembles the last modified date (i.e. a User record is updated).

Is there a last modified field for Users endpoint of Microsoft Graph that should be enabled somewhere first? Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `lastModifiedDateTime`  or similar  property in MS Graph.

But If your scenario is about on-premises AD data(user object) is sync to Azure AD then there is a possibility.We can get user modified /updated field changes from `onPremisesLastSyncDateTime` property.

Also, If you want the last  password change for the user then you can query with `lastPasswordChangeDateTime`.

Comment: would the sync to Azure AD only concern AD data that has been updated?

Comment: Yes that is the scenario.

Comment: I'm trying to perform a similar operation and retrieve only recently modified user profile photos or, lacking that, the last modified date of the user record to limit downloads. In the nearly 3-years since this thread started, has MS updated the Graph API to be able to get this information about a user profile pic or the user records?